# Mysqldump update table

Tags: mysql

I use the mysqldump utility to dump the database on the test server, which runs on the crown.

Mysqldump --host = 127.0.0.1 --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --no-create-info --user = root --password = 'root' stead> tead.sql

On production for import use:

Mysql --user = root --password = 'root' test

It also starts on the crown.

The dump file contains approximately the following information.

INSERT INTO `im_gruppy` VALUES (100, 'Paper for office equipment', 1, '100.png', 1);

The problem is that when insert finds Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY', import stops. And I would like to update the old records.

Prompt as it is possible by means of mysqldump and mysql to do update lines and if a line is not present that insert?

Comment: Erm, what? There's no updating. Like you said yourself, the whole table gets dropped, there are no rows to update, then they are freshly inserted.

Comment: Use SELECT * FROM 'im_gruppy' and this will return a list of all the records you have inserted into the table, in this case, the one record you have inserted

Comment: When I start importing to another server. I do not pass the ladies since most of the records I already have. I need to first update them which are already there. But which are not inserted. And I have to do this from the server console (ubuntu).

Tell me how it can be implemented?

Comment: mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --no-create-info --user=root --password='root' stead > stead.sql
The insertion does not occur if it finds a match on the keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --no-create-info **--replace** --user=root --password='root' stead > tead.sql